# Functional Equation f(n+2023)=f(f(f(f(n))))

Tags: functions, contest-math

Consider the functional equation $$ f(n+2023) = f(f(f(f(n))))$$ for all $n \in\Bbb N$.
Find all strictly increasing functions $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ satisfying above conditions.

I assume it's a linear function as it is supposed to be strictly increasing. Don't have any clue how to properly write proof for this question and solve it.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: A strictly increasing function over the naturals do not have to be linear, e.g. $f(n) = 2^n$.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Questions involving the current year frequently appear in contests and such.

Comment: I encountered this question while going through this year's question in National Olympiad Nepal.

Answer (score 2):

We claim that such $f$ doesn't exist:

Assume it exists, first notice that $f(f(f(n)))=n+2023$, as $f$ is strictly increasing. Assume $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(k)\ge k+675$. Then inductively it's clear that for any $l\ge k$, $l\in\mathbb{N}$, we must have $f(l)\ge l+675$. In particular, $f(f(f(l)))\ge f(f(l))+675\ge f(l)+1350\ge l+2025>l+2023$, contradiction.

Therefore, $f(n)\leq n+674$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $f(f(f(n)))\leq f(f(n))+674\leq f(n)+1348\leq n+2022<n+2023$, contradiction, allowing to conclude.

Comment: This might be tight as with $2022$ instead $n+674$ works. Could this be someone actualized the problem for $2023$ not realizing that for $f(n+a)$ to work (i.e. having affine solution) $a$ should be divisible by $3$ ?

Comment: I think the solution is unique iff $3|a$. The "$\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$" condition is a good restriction of the number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since **strictly increasing** implies **injective**, our functional equation gives
$$n+2023 = f(f(f(n)))\tag{$\star$}$$

> **Lemma.** Let $a, b\in\mathbb N$ be such that $f(a)=f(b)+1$. Then $a = b+1$.

**Proof.** Of course $f(a)>f(b)$ so $a>b$. Now suppose $a>b+1$. So $f(b)+1 = f(a) > f(b+1) > f(b)$, i.e., there is a natural number between $f(b)$ and $f(b)+1$. Contradiction! $\square$

Now just notice that $f(f(f(n+1))) = n+2024 = f(f(f(n)))+1$, so
$$\begin{aligned}
&f(f(f(n+1))) = f(f(f(n)))+1\\
\implies &f(f(n+1)) = f(f(n))+1\\
\implies &f(n+1) = f(n)+1
\end{aligned}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$. By induction we show that $f(n) = f(0)+n$. Therefore $$f(f(f(n))) = f(0)+f(f(n)) = 2f(0)+f(n) = 3f(0)+n$$
but, in order for that to work, we should have $3f(0) = 2023$, which can't be solved over the naturals.

We conclude there can not be such a function.

Comment: I didn't understand the f(b)+1=f(a)>f(b+1)>f(b) part of the solution.

Comment: $f(b)+1 = f(a)$ because that is our hypothesis.

$f(a) > f(b+1)$ because we are supposing $a>b+1$ and our function is strictly increasing.

$f(b+1) > f(b)$ because $b+1>b$ and, again, our function is strictly increasing. 

As this leads to a contradiction, our hypothesis must be false, i.e., $a$ can't be greater than $b+1$. Because $a > b$, the only possibility left is $a = b+1$.